# Gatsby: Apply new theme to starter

Tags: reactjs, themes, config, gatsby, ghost-blog

I'm new to Gatsby and I started a project using a starter, [Gatsby-starter-ghost](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost/). The starter comes with the Casper theme, and now I want to replace Casper with a new theme or build a custom theme.

I can't figure out how to replace Casper or even find where it is in the project folders. There is a lot of documentation available on Gatsby themes and starters but I can barely find any documentation for `gatsby-starter-ghost`. I've dug through the `node_modules` and `src` folders and can't even find where the Casper theme is located. If I install a new theme with npm and put the plugin in the `gatsby-config` file it breaks my project and I get GraphQL errors galore. I've read that themes should usually be in the `content` folder, but my `content` folder contains nothing but two empty folders.

Here is my project structure:

[image]
[image]

How do I replace the theme in the `gatsby-ghost-starter`?

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby Themes use a concept called '[shadowing](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/themes/shadowing/)'. You can replace any of the default files for the theme by placing a file with the same path and name in your content folder. This is probably why your folder doesn't have any theme files, the starter is just using all the defaults.

That said, looking at gatsby-starter-ghost, it doesn't look like it's using a Gatsby Theme at all, so shadowing doesn't apply.

If you look at `gatsby-starter-ghost/src/components/common/`, it has various files which define the components that are being used. Most notably, Layout.js is setting out the base structure for every page, and imports a CSS file from `../../styles/app.css`.

This CSS, those common components, as well as the various template files in `src/templates` are what is defining the HTML structure of the pages, and the CSS that those use. If you adjust those, you should be able to change the design to suit your needs.

Start by looking at `app.css` and adjusting it a bit, see how far that takes you. But you may need to update the components if you want to introduce new classes or change the HTML structure.